# Filtering from union type to subtype

Tags: typescript

When I use .filter to filter from array union types A and B to array of one of its sub types A, I get the following error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.

```js
type A = {type: "a"};
type B = {type: "b"};
type AB = A | B;

let ab: AB[] = [{type: "a"}, {type: "b"}];

let res: A[] = ab.filter(item => item.type === "a");
```

Is there some way to properly type this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a type assertion as other answers sugest, you can also use a custom type guard as `filter` supports them

```
type A = {type: "a"};
type B = {type: "b"};
type AB = A | B;

let ab: AB[] = [{type: "a"}, {type: "b"}];

let res: A[] = ab.filter((item): item is A => item.type === "a");
```

Comment: I was in the middle of typing this out too  ... you can have the [relevant library link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1151) if you'd like it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`filter` typing returns the same type as the source array. I believe the only way you can get around this is adding a type assertion:

```
ab.filter(item => item.type === "a") as A[]
                                  // ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map array like this: `let numbers = ab.filter(item => item.type === "a") as A[];`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20A%20%3D%20%7Btype%3A%20%22a%22%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7Btype%3A%20%22b%22%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20AB%20%3D%20A%20%7C%20B%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20ab%3A%20AB%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7Btype%3A%20%22a%22%7D%2C%20%7Btype%3A%20%22b%22%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20numbers%20%3D%20ab.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22a%22)%20as%20A%5B%5D%3B)